# python selenium send css with !important

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium

I would like to change the css of the element as follows. It works fine when:

```
browser.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].style.display = 'block';",
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='main']/div/div/div["+str(d)+"]/div["+str(r)+"]/div/div[2]")
)
```

but when I try to add the "!important", the code was not updated:

```
browser.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].style.display = 'block!important';",
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='main']/div/div/div["+str(d)+"]/div["+str(r)+"]/div/div[2]")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement element.style.display = 'block' will only work for setting the value of *valid* property values. Since 'block !important' is not recognized, it will not be added. !important itself is a declaration.

You can use .setProperty() instead, which will let you add more than the value. Use 'important' as a string and don't add the exclamation point.

```
browser.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');",
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div")
    )
```